# Set workflow model id (path)

Tags: aem

When I create a new workflow model in AEM, it gets created under /etc/workflow/models. How do I get it to be created under a different path like /etc/workflow/models/myapp ? The only way I can think of is changing the path in CRXDE after the workflow gets created. Wanted so if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better way to move workflow to another place would be:

- go to `/miscadmin#/etc/workflow/models`
- use button "Move..."

Unfortunately, it seems, that there is no easy way to change place, where worflows, which are created through UI, are stored. To do this you should:

- override "/libs/cq/workflow/widgets/source/widget/ModelsPanel.js" in you project, where you can find action `this.newAction`, where you will be able to change propery `parentPath` to `/etc/workflow/models/myapp`. But you can run into troubles after upgrading to another version of AEM.
- also you can be interested in service `Granite Workflow Service` where you can set (through `/system/console/configMgr`) path to your models, which should be shown in Workflow Console `/libs/cq/workflow/content/console.html`. (Also it's applicable to CQ 5.6.1, for some older versions, you should configure `Day CQ Workflow Service`).